# Possible to aggregate and filter on same key?

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm not very experienced with Elastic but is it possible to aggregate and filter on the same key?

Say I want to be able to filter on the city and aggregate on the department ID for counts of a certain department in that city, but also be able to filter on that as well. Think of it as a checkbox for the city, then children checkboxes under city which can also be filtered on, or 'checked'.

This may be a dumb question but is there anyway to do this? I know it is invalid JSON due to the same key (department.id). Would the pipeline aggregation be something viable to use?

The top query would be a "match_all" query.

Aggregations such as:

```
"aggregations": {
"department.id": {
    "terms": {
        "field": "department.id",
        "size": 10
    }
},
"department.id": {
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "city": ["chicago"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: yeah you can do this, you can follow my this answer to this question where the filtering is done using range on a date field and then a date histogram filter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603723/which-elasticsearch-aggregations-should-i-use/46606574#46606574

Comment: So the filter needs to be before the term aggregation for my query? The problem is the incorrect ID's of 'department.id'. The other has two different keys and separate aggregations. Mine is under the umbrella of 'aggregations'.

Comment: yeah exactly, even you can place the filter in the query part instead of agg part, if you are not using the hits

Comment: If putting it in the query part isn't an option would it need to fall outside of the aggregation umbrella so there are no children with the same key?

Comment: this has to be within the aggregation then like in the other post

Comment: but then there will still be a duplicate key of department.id. I just tried to put the filter prior to the term aggregation.